# Issue in path to a file in assets folder of android

Tags: android

i know it is basic but stuck. i gave a file path like this

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/xls/x.xlsx";
File f = new File(path);
```

I am getting Filenotfound exception and path it is showing **file:/android_asset/xls/x.xlsx** which is wrong because i want **"file:///android_asset/xls/x.xlsx"**. Any help ? thanks

Comment: i am not sure but may be you shouldnt put the extension? I mean just "x" instead of "x.xlsx"?

Comment: are you certain the file is present ?

Comment: @njzk2 yes file is present for sure

Comment: why do you need the file for ?

Comment: @njzk2 i need that to pass to FileInputStream as a instance as a parameter. But the problem is that the path i am using should work directly and fine.

Comment: you can get an inputstream using `getResources().getAssets().open`. There are very few cases in which one really needs a fileinputstream and cannot use just any inputstream.

Comment: "yes file is present for sure" -- on your development machine, perhaps, but not on the device, because assets are not files. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK file. "i need that to pass to FileInputStream as a instance as a parameter" -- hopefully you just need an `InputStream`, in which case you can use `getAssets().open()` to retrieve one.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks sir for replying. i am actually using POI library to read xlsx file. i did a java example putting the file inside my system itself and giving path and it worked. But when i copy paste the same code and put the file inside either asset or raw, it is not finding the path.

Comment: That is because **there is no path** to an asset or raw resource, because **there is no file** for the asset or raw resource on the filesystem. Moreover, since assets and raw resources cannot be modified, it is *pointless* for you to be packaging an XSLX file, unless you are planning on copying it to internal (or external) storage so that the copy can be modified. Otherwise, you may as well use a file format that is easier to use, without a third-party library like POI.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like that

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("x.xlsx");
```

if your file have inner folder in assets folder then try this way

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open(file:///android_asset/xls/x.xlsx);
```

or try like this

```
InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("xls/x.xlsx");
File file = createFileFromInputStream(is);
```

if you want the file object then use this

```
final File createFileFromInputStream(InputStream is);

try{
   File f=new File(my_file_name);
   OutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(f);
   byte buffer[]=new byte[1024];
   int length=0;

   while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))>0) {
     outputStream.write(buffer,0,length);
   }
   outputStream.close();
   inputStream.close();

}catch (IOException e){
      //Logging exception
}
```

Comment: I know this but i need file object 'f'.

Comment: i saw this code but i didnt try this out. let me try and get back to u. The problem is that the path i m using shud work directly and fine. I want to know what is the problem thr.